# How to obtain "this" object in Fay?

Tags: jquery, haskell, fay

Given this HTML:

```
  <div class="blah" id="div1">a</div>
  <div class="blah" id="div2">b</div>
```

I'm trying do make a handler depend on the value of "this", like in the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blah").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); }); });
```

How to do it in Fay? I didn't find API to do this. It looks like it's impossible to call ffi directly from main:

```
main = ready $ do
  select ".blah" >>= onClick (\_ ->
    ffi "alert(this.id)")
```

I get "Test$ffi is not defined". I managed to call ffi using the code below:

```
alertthis = ffi "alert(this.id)"
main = ready $ do
  select ".blah" >>= onClick (\_ ->
    alertthis)
```

But now "this" refers to some Fay-specific object and doesn't have the property "id".

Comment: The error message does not refer to `this`, maybe something else is broken. Does `ffi alert('Test')` in that code work?

Comment: You're right, ffi "alert('test')" doesn't work either. I reformulated the question. I still can't find the way to get "this".

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you got, i get `fay: unable to resolve qualified names ffi` instead. It doesn't matter for your question, but are you running the latest version of Fay (0.18.*)?

Comment: @AdamBergmark I get the same error for everything; have you ever been able to resolve this?

Comment: @JustinL. I released fay 0.19.0.2 to improve these error messages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have a type signature for your ffi calls, either make a toplevel declaration (I thought fay would give an error on this, but perhaps it doesn't, should fix that):

```
alert :: sometype -> Fay ()
alert = ffi "alert(%1)"
```

or use it at the expression level:

```
(\_ -> (ffi "alert(%1)" :: sometype -> Fay ()) myThis))
```

`this` isn't available in a Fay function because it doesn't have the same representation as a js function, there are some conversions happening so `this` gets lost in the process.

We decided that it's not good to depend on `this` being bound anyway. You didn't give the definition for your `onClick` function, but presumably the argument you are ignoring in the callback contains the event object which has a `target` property. This doesn't always work out because of event propagation, if that's a problem you can pass `this` to it as well, something like

```
onClick :: (Element -> Event -> Fay ()) -> JQuery -> Fay JQuery
onClick = ffi "%2.click(function (e) { %1(this, e); })"
```